# Get Date of Joining and Date of Birth of all users from Active Directory in C#,SharePoint2013

Tags: development, sharepoint-on-prem

I want to retrieve date of joining (hire date) and date of birth (Birthdate) of every user from  Active directory. How can I achieve this?
i tried something like

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

but here it is only working with mapping attribute name,rather internal or display name,and this birth date and hire date column doesn't have mapping attribute name,so how can i get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the bellow code that is for retrieving current users data

include the name spaces

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
```

apply the following code

```
       using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)) ;
            {
                SPUser spuser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
                var userLoginName = user.LoginName;
                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                var userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(userLoginName);
                var name = userProfile.DisplayName.ToString();
                var BirthDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(userProfile["SPS-Birthday"].Value).ToLocalTime();
                var HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(userProfile["SPS-HireDate"].Value).ToLocalTime();
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Birthday: " + BirthDateTime);
                Console.WriteLine("Hire date: " + HireDate);
            }
```

and check the bellow code for retrieving all users for current site

```
       using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
                {
                    var name = profile.DisplayName.ToString();
                    var BirthDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(profile["SPS-Birthday"].Value).ToLocalTime();
                    var HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(profile["SPS-HireDate"].Value).ToLocalTime();
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Birthday: " + BirthDateTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Hire date: " + HireDate);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

User's Properties from Active Directory can be achieved through profile synchronization.

- In Central Administration, verify settings on user profile service synchronization properties
- Run “User profile service synchronization" service. This will update all the user profile information

With the help of CSOM and REST API you can perform an activity to retrieve Hire date and birthday.
Internal name of hire date: “SPS-HireDate” and birthday : “SPS-Birthday”

Example:

```
    var userProfileProperties;
// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.

SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {
    // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
    var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Specify the properties to retrieve and target user for the 
    // UserProfilePropertiesForUser object.
    var profilePropertyNames = ["SPS-HireDate", "SPS-Birthday"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = 
        new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
            clientContext,
            targetUser,
            profilePropertyNames);

    // Get user profile properties for the target user.
    // To get the value for only one user profile property, use the
    // getUserProfilePropertyFor method.
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(
        userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    // Load the UserProfilePropertiesForUser object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {
    var messageText = "\"Hire date \" property is " 
        + userProfileProperties[0];
    messageText += "<br />\"DOB\" property is " 
        + userProfileProperties[1];
    $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

Reference:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-a-particular-users-properties-using-csom-in-shar/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx
http://nikhilsarvaiye.blogspot.in/2013/09/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html
https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/default-user-profile-properties/

Comment: thanks,but i want to achieve the same using CS code rather javascript

Comment: For C# use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles; this name space. Reference link :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-a-particular-users-properties-using-csom-in-shar/

Answer (score 0):

You need to know Active directory programming with C#. Following reference is very helpful.

[Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C)

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#26) section will help you to read user properties like joining date and etc.

Comment: that is absolutely fine,but how can i get the internal names of those fields?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#26